# How can I print chinese and cyrillic characters in ZPL via Java?

Tags: java, printing, cjk, zpl, cyrillic

I want to print chinese and cyrillics character on zpl printer. I installed SIMSUN.FNT and SWISS271 Cyrillic and linked them with ^CW tag and after call them whith ^A but it not works on my zebra printer! Someone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you are sending the label format in UTF-8 and have configured the printer to use UTF-8 via the `^CI28` command.  The `^CI` command should always be placed at the top of the label format, after the `^XA` but before any formatting commands.